# How to restore all items from trash

Tags: backup, trash

I have accidentally deleted a WP user. By deleting it, WP removed all the media files, pages etc.

I could retrieve pages and posts from trash. But I could not restore media items. Is there a way to restore all items from trash back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deleting a user, WordPress displays a warning that unless you attribute the user's posts to a new user, it's posts will be deleted and you cannot undo those deletions.

That means the only way to restore the posts and media is to restore a backup of the WordPress instance or database which you hopefully have.

Comment: Ok, I understand. In fact, I saw the warning. But I was in a hurry. My mind had some other concerns. And I didn't even spend a second about the warning :) Human psychology beats any warning.

Comment: For what it's worth, I completely agree that the workflow of this sucks.